# PIC 18F26K83 ADC clock frequency

Tags: pic, adc

Hello I am using PIC18F26K83 and I need to use ADC module in it, in order to measure voltage value of a spesific pin. MCU clock frequency is 8 MHz. This PIC has 12-bit ADC inside of it. So my question is: How should I select the ADC clock frequency. I have seen that people say acquisition time must be at least 1.6 us.2 to 6 us is preferred. So I have 8 MHz system clock. Which makes 0.125 us. Fortunately I can divide this down. Now I have 2 questions.

1. I am not sure but I think for my MCU it takes 4 clock cycles for 1 operation. Should I consider this while I am trying to calculate the Tac? If yes then without any division period will be 0.5 us instead of 0.125. Then I can divide my MCU clock by 8 and I will get 4 us Tac. Does it sound correct?
2. In the datasheet there is a picture like this:
   [image: ADCLK register]

according to this image if I want to divide my Fosc by 8 I need to set this register to: 0b00000010 right? and 0b00000011 for dividing 16 and it goes like this. Is it the correct pattern? I just want to be sure. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You shouldn't need to take this into consideration. Fosc is the oscillator frequency (system clock). FCY is the instruction clock which is Fosc/4. The selections for CS in ADCLK refer to Fosc and not FCY. see table TABLE 37-1 in datasheet.
2. division of 16 should give you conversion clock of 2us (if Fosc=8MHz). You'll notice increments of two per 1 bit and starting at 2.

```
    div 2 =  000000
    div 4 =  000001
    div 6 =  000010
    div 8 =  000011
    div 10 = 000100
    div 12 = 000101
    div 14 = 000110
    div 16 = 000111
```

i.e.

`ADCLK.CS = (div / 2) - 1`

Comment: Thanks! So what would be the proper divider for Fosc in ADC clock? Do you have any idea related to it?

Comment: Just to repeat -- "division of 16 should give you conversion clock of 2us (if Fosc=8MHz)" i.e. ADCLK.CS = 0b000111